# Proxy IP address shared instead of proxy name when shared via mobile

Tags: laravel-5, share, domain-name

I face a problem whenever I try to share my page via mobile. Let's say the shared domain name is `example.com`, and when I share some of its pages (`www.example.com/myblog`) from Chrome or Safari browsers on my mobile, instead of the proxy name a proxy IP is shared (`12.35.79.4/myblog`)

I’m using Laravel framework and I have set reverse proxy setting in `AppServiceProvider`.

This is the screenshot of what happens when I share from my mobile:

http://prnt.sc/nkxfj5

And this is what happens when the proxy IP is shared instead of the actual domain name:

http://prnt.sc/nkxg8f

Comment: how do you compute the shared url? Which laravel functions you use? You should instead use the public domain name directly and only add current path

Comment: Thanks Nikos, I’m not using custom share. It’s an mobile browser default share.